# Javascript Replacing all confirm and Alert dialogs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

We are starting to use the bootbox plugin for nicer alert dialogs and confirm dialogs on our site.

does anyone know if there happens to be an easy way to automatically replace the alert dialog with this plugin ?

Example

```
<script>
  alert = bootbox.alert();
</script>
```

Comment: first problem could be that the `bootbox` plugin methods are asynchronous

Comment: You can't quite make a drop-in replacement for JavaScript's built-in dialog methods, because those methods return the user's response. DOM-altering functions like bootbox's own, by contrast, have to return before they can gather data on the user's response, so they can't return that data.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/alert/bootbox.alert/g' `find ./ -iname \*.js`
```

(NOTE: Have a backup before you run that ;)

(NOTE2: Does not address the fact that bootbox.alert is not synchronous - as Arun P Johny mentions.)

Answer (score 0):

This managed to resolve the problem for me.

```
<script>
    window.alert = function(message) {bootbox.alert( message); }
</script>
```

Seems to process the alert dialog into view with all the required messages, and stops the user dead in their tracks.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Vex](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/docs/welcome/). Just include in on your page, and from then on use:

```
vex.dialog.alert('Hello world!')
```

Vex is highly configurable and has many themes.